# Convert link syntax to links embedded in text UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, hyperlink, uitextview

Given some text of the form [text here](link here), how do I display that in a UITextView as "google" where the "google" is clickable and links to www.google.com?

I'm assuming that this is solved through some combination of regex and NSAttributedString. Also, I need to maintain good scrolling performance as there will be up to 250 cells containing a UITextView. I have tried writing the logic to make this but due to my insufficient knowledge of regex, I didn't make much progress. Also, the logic of keeping track of which ranges were the real text and which were the links and where the link attribute needed to be added proved very difficult.

Comment: It sounds like you want to render Markdown - take a look at this https://github.com/indragiek/CocoaMarkdown

Answer (score 0):

You could use NSDataDetector to detect URLs inside a string:

```
let string = "Google is at http://www.google.com "
let linkDetector = NSDataDetector(pattern: NSTextCheckingType.Link.rawValue, options: nil)
```

Comment: I'm concerned with converting [text here](link here) to clickable *text here*. The comment sschale left has pointed me in the right direction.